# Liquibase maven plugin - set logging level

Tags: java, maven-plugin, liquibase

There is a liquibase-maven-plugin <3.6.2> in the project pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>src/test/resources/liquibase/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Documentation says:

> logging:

Controls the level of logging from Liquibase when executing. The value can be "debug", "info", "warning", "severe", or "off". The value is case insensitive.
Type: java.lang.String
Required: No
Expression: ${liquibase.logging}
Default: INFO

I did not catch how to apply it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are few ways to set it:

1. Using command line

   ```
   mvn -Dliquibase.logging=debug
   ```
2. Using pom properties

   ```
   <properties>
       <liquibase.logging>debug</liquibase.logging>
   </properties>
   ```
3. Setting it directly in plugin's `<configuration>`

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
       <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <logging>debug</logging>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have used it in my project number of time with pom property and it works.

```
<properties>
    <liquibase.logging>debug</liquibase.logging>
</properties>
```